# Unable to click the link using selenium webdriver Version 3.0.0.beta3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the below Junit code to click on the **`Sign In`** link present on the **quikr** website below
**http://www.quikr.com/**.

The code runs fine without any errors but the webdriver doesn't seems to be clicking the **`Sign In`** link on the website. Please suggest.

**I'm using:**

**OS:** Win10

**Slenium WebDriver:** Version 3.0.0.beta3

**Firefox browser version:** 49.0.1

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Quikr {
    @Test
    public void loginTest(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.quikr.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='responsiveHeader']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span[1]")).isEmpty()){
             System.out.println("Link present");
         }else{
             System.out.println("Link not present");
         }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='responsiveHeader']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span[1]")).click();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really strange one. There's something about this page that isn't allowing clicks until the page fully loads... and it does an initial load and then triggers a second load of ads. I can't find a way to click that link without a huge wait. There's probably another way to do this right but I can't think of how. The code below works for me (but is ugly).

```
driver.get("http://www.quikr.com/");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.sign-in")).click();
```

Using `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice and should be avoided in 99% of scenarios. `WebDriverWait` is the preferred way to wait for an element, etc.

Comment: I was able to click on the 'Sign In' link using the above code you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the answer but I will add a dynamic wait time instead of the hard-coded one that was given as an answer. You can use this method before doing the click in the desired button.

```
    public static void waitForPageToLoad(long timeOutInSeconds) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for page to load");
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for page to load...");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
        wait.until(expectation);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        System.out.println(
                "Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete after " + timeOutInSeconds + " seconds");
    }
}
```